# Datadog APM Trace not returning logs for .NET

Tags: .net, iis, datadog, apm

Tried installing Datadog APM trace for .NET. The agent got installed and I configured the environment variable showed in the documentation. The APM trace version installed is 2.4.3 agent version :- 7.33.1. As told in the documentation I have enabled the APM trace and logs.

> $target=[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine
> [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DD_ENV","env",$target)
> [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DD_VERSION","version",$target)
> [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DD_LOGS_INJECTION","true",$target)
>
> net stop was /y
>
> net start w3svc

The Datadog .NET Tracer is not showing any logs and the trace_agent logs in Datadog directory gives the following message:

> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | WARN | (pkg/util/log/log.go:640 in
> func1) | Unknown key in config file: dd_trace_debug
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | WARN | (pkg/util/log/log.go:640 in
> func1) | Unknown key in config file: enabled
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | WARN | (pkg/util/log/log.go:640 in
> func1) | Unknown environment variable: DD_DOTNET_TRACER_HOME
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | WARN | (pkg/util/log/log.go:640 in
> func1) | Unknown environment variable: DD_LOGS_INJECTION
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | WARN | (pkg/util/log/log.go:640 in
> func1) | Unknown environment variable: DD_PROFILING_ENABLED
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | WARN | (pkg/util/log/log.go:640 in
> func1) | Unknown environment variable: DD_RUNTIME_METRICS_ENABLED
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | WARN | (pkg/util/log/log.go:640 in
> func1) | Unknown environment variable: DD_TRACE_DEBUG
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | WARN | (pkg/util/log/log.go:640 in
> func1) | Unknown environment variable: DD_TRACE_SAMPLE_RATE
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | WARN | (pkg/util/log/log.go:640 in
> func1) | Unknown environment variable: DD_VERSION
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | INFO | (pkg/util/log/log.go:620 in
> func1) | Features detected from environment:
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | INFO | (pkg/util/log/log.go:620 in
> func1) | Loaded configuration: C:\ProgramData\Datadog\datadog.yaml
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | DEBUG | (pkg/util/log/log.go:600 in
> func1) | Setting DefaultEnv to "prod" (from 'env' config option)
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | DEBUG | (pkg/util/log/log.go:600 in
> func1) | attempting to create grpc agent client connection to:
> localhost:5001
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | DEBUG | (pkg/util/log/log.go:595 in
> func1) | grpc agent client created
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | DEBUG | (pkg/util/log/log.go:600 in
> func1) | Acquired hostname from gRPC: AG-Lap
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | INFO |
> (pkg/tagger/remote/tagger.go:337 in func1) | tagger stream established
> successfully
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | INFO |
> (pkg/tagger/remote/tagger.go:110 in Init) | remote tagger initialized
> successfully
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | DEBUG |
> (pkg/trace/writer/trace.go:110 in NewTraceWriter) | Trace writer
> initialized (climit=200 qsize=78)
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | DEBUG |
> (pkg/trace/writer/stats.go:86 in NewStatsWriter) | Stats writer
> initialized (climit=20 qsize=83)
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | INFO | (pkg/trace/agent/run.go:176
> in Run) | Trace agent running on host AG-Lap
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | INFO | (pkg/trace/api/api.go:168 in
> Start) | Listening for traces at http://localhost:8126
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:06 IST | TRACE | DEBUG |
> (pkg/trace/stats/concentrator.go:87 in Run) | Starting concentrator
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:16 IST | TRACE | INFO | (pkg/trace/info/stats.go:104
> in LogStats) | No data received
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:26 IST | TRACE | DEBUG |
> (pkg/trace/stats/concentrator.go:194 in flushNow) | update oldestTs to
> 1646390290000000000
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:36 IST | TRACE | DEBUG |
> (pkg/trace/stats/concentrator.go:194 in flushNow) | update oldestTs to
> 1646390300000000000
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:46 IST | TRACE | DEBUG |
> (pkg/trace/stats/concentrator.go:194 in flushNow) | update oldestTs to
> 1646390310000000000
>
> 2022-03-04 16:08:56 IST | TRACE | DEBUG |
> (pkg/trace/stats/concentrator.go:194 in flushNow) | update oldestTs to
> 1646390320000000000
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:06 IST | TRACE | DEBUG |
> (pkg/trace/stats/concentrator.go:194 in flushNow) | update oldestTs to
> 1646390330000000000
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:09 IST | TRACE | INFO | (pkg/trace/agent/agent.go:156
> in loop) | Exiting...
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:09 IST | TRACE | INFO |
> (pkg/trace/stats/concentrator.go:102 in Run) | Exiting concentrator,
> computing remaining stats
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:09 IST | TRACE | DEBUG |
> (pkg/trace/writer/trace.go:117 in Stop) | Exiting trace writer. Trying
> to flush whatever is left...
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:09 IST | TRACE | WARN |
> (pkg/tagger/remote/tagger.go:239 in run) | error received from remote
> tagger: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:09 IST | TRACE | WARN |
> (pkg/tagger/remote/tagger.go:246 in run) | error received trying to
> start stream: tagger stream not started
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:09 IST | TRACE | INFO |
> (pkg/tagger/remote/tagger.go:132 in Stop) | remote tagger stopped
> successfully
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:19 IST | TRACE | DEBUG | (pkg/util/log/log.go:600 in
> func1) | Loaded features: []
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:19 IST | TRACE | DEBUG | (pkg/util/log/log.go:600 in
> func1) | cloud_provider_metadata is set to [aws gcp azure alibaba] in
> agent configuration, trying endpoints for AWS Cloud Provider
>
> 2022-03-04 16:09:19 IST | TRACE | DEBUG | (pkg/util/log/log.go:600 in
> func1) | cloud_provider_metadata is set to [aws gcp azure alibaba] in
> agent configuration, trying endpoints for AWS Cloud Provider

Is there any mistake in the configuration and is there a way to get the APM Trace?

Answer (score 0):

The datadog-agent needs

```
DD_API_KEY=__your_datadog_api_key_here__
```

**your_datadog_api_key_here** can be your organization key or personal key